# Change baseline color of search view

Tags: android, layout, screen, android-xml, scaling

I am using the support library, how can I change the color of the baseline, which is blue, when starting to enter a search query into the input field:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You should use `android:textColorHighlight` in the EditText  element in you layout xml file

Comment: There is no layout geekCode. This is also no EditText element.